# white screen in webview

Tags: android, flash, video, webview

Have blank white screen when using Webview. I see many topics with this problem but no one solved. So i tried another one...
It's my first time project on android.

Ok i optimised my code but its still show me gray screen on emulator and white screen on device. Someine help me.

```
public class Video extends Activity{

private WebView video;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    video = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webshow);
    video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    video.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    /*video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);*/
    String html = "http://www.twitch.tv/wingsofdeath";
final String temp = "<div class=\"live_site_player_container swf_container js-player-container\" data-channel=\"wingsofdeath\" id=\"standard_holder\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 211px;\">\n" +
        "<object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" name=\"live_site_player_flash\" data=\"http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" id=\"live_site_player_flash\" style=\"visibility: visible;\"><param name=\"allowNetworking\" value=\"all\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"opaque\"><param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"team=solomid&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_chat=true&amp;publisherGuard=null&amp;publisherTimezoneOffset=420&amp;channel=wingsofdeath&amp;hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;loadCallback=Twitch.player._twitchPlayerLoaded&amp;backgroundImageUrl=http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/anonymous_monkey-320x240.jpg\"></object>\n" +
        "</div>";
    video.loadDataWithBaseURL (html, temp, "application/x-shockwave-flash", "UTF-8","");


}}
```

what i doing wrong?? Someone talk about using webchromeclent. pls explain me about that.
(Manifest and another.. is right)
Thank you.

Can i get info about "file///android_asset" its local html file as i stand... how i can load my data there if it's possible??

Comment: This is a pretty funny variable name:  final String temp  (its final, but its temp, but its final, ya know)  It doesn't cause any problems, though, because its just a funny name.